# how to find out network traffic for a query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

On a production PostgreSQL  server I am seeing intermittent enormous spikes in data traffic. Up to 400Mbit/s which is causing NETWORK IO waits which in turn cause query timeouts. How can I find out what queries are returning big result sets?

Comment: You could try to identify slow statements using the auto_explain module, assuming those that have a high network traffic are also slow

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql lacks metrics for network traffic usage.

There was some [patches](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAHhq2wJXRqTMJXZwMAOdtQOkxSKxg_aMxxofhvCo%3DRGXvh0AUg%40mail.gmail.com#CAHhq2wJXRqTMJXZwMAOdtQOkxSKxg_aMxxofhvCo=RGXvh0AUg@mail.gmail.com) for such metrics, but nothing related has been merged at the moment.

---

[`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) extension could track total number of rows retrieved or affected by the statement (`rows` metric). Doesn't help if you are sending large text/json/bytea/etc in one row. But it will tell you the places in which many rows are transmitted.

PS: are you sure the bottleneck is the network IO on postgresql side? 400 Mbps is not too much, I have several gigabytes of upstream traffic on some of the database servers.

Comment: Agreed 400 Mbps seems low. I believe most modern networks have at least 2.5x (1 Gbps) bandwidths as a minimum.